# AS3: Getting the index of the highest value in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is there any way to actually get the index of the highest value stored in an array?

Like for example

`var rate:Array = [10, 15, 12];`

how will I know if the highest value in the array resides at index #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many sorting algorithms in Data Structure which can help you achieve that.
Bubble Sort is the highest among all.

Apart from that you can use the Math function in JS to achieve the same.

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
// Where 'values' is the array stored on your application.
```

Comment: Err.. JS? Don't you mean flash? :D Umm.. If i can get the highest value, how will I know what index was it from? or what is the index in the array that has the highest value?

Comment: you can use the map() method of array to traverse through and and then compare the value to get the highest value.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {if (values[i]==highest) {return i;}}

Comment: well **this** actually worked! I used a combination of loops and switches to achieve what I wanted to happen. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need only one loop. Copy the values into an array of objects that know both the index and the value, then use the sortOn method and return the last item in the resulting array.

```
var arr:Array = [10,15,12];
var temp:Array = [];
arr.forEach( function( item:int, index:int, self:Array ) :void {
    temp[temp.length] = {index:index, value: item};
});
var result:Array = temp.sortOn( "value", Array.NUMERIC ); // returns 1
```